# org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance

Tags: hibernate

Hi all currently I'm using Hibernate  4.1.5 , i tried in different ways. But I'm unable to resolve the issue.
Because of this issue my production server becomes hanging.

Any help would be great. Thanks!

### ISSUE DESCRIPTION:

Trying to rollback database transaction after exception

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
 omegon.bo.exam.ExamQuestionAttemptBO
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:459)
        at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.isDirty(ManyToOneType.java:276)
:
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with saving the dependent objects...

For example, class A contains relation with class B - assume its one to many with the primary key of B.

Save B instance first, so that the relation - foreign key relation(ID) with A will be available before saving A.

Visit [this link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) for an example.

Comment: Hi vinany thx for your reply  i will give my BO's check it once let me know plz

parent:

        @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
 @Column(name = "EXAM_ATTEMPT_ID")
 private long id;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "attempt", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
 private List<ExamQuestionAttemptBO> questionAttempts;